# sed on mac: how to print a new-line for every range-match

Tags: macos, sed

For range-matches, wondering how to print a new line along with the match.

For example,
if the content of a file called context.txt is like

```
one
begin
two
three
end
four
begin
five 
six
end
seven
```

then, this is the output I get with the following sed command

```
$ sed -n -e '/begin/,/end/p' content.txt 
begin
two
three
end
begin
five 
six
end
```

Instead, how can I get the output like the following:-

```
begin
two
three
end

begin
five 
six
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n -e '/begin/,/end/{/end/G;p;}' file
```

Print the range `begin` to `end` and append the hold space when `end` matches.

See [here](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one) for one liner explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output through `sed` again:

```
 sed -n -e '/begin/,/end/p' content.txt | sed 's/^end$/end\n/'
```

Comment: was throwing an error for me with the substitution part(I'm a new-bee with sed, can't figure out the issue ```$  sed -n -e '/begin/,/end/p' content.txt | sed 's/^end$/end\n'
sed: 1: "s/^end$/end\n": unterminated substitute in regular expression```

Comment: @raj I accidentally left off a `/`. See edited answer.

Comment: thanks. Now it gives me the output in the desired format. Answer from @potong is more concise though :)

Comment: @Raj I'm a bit like you though - not a sed guru, so I go for the easy to read and understand option

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
/^end$/{
  if(found){
     print val ORS $0 ORS
  }
  found=val=""
}
/^begin$/{
  val=""
  found=1
}
found{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
/^end$/{                      ##checking condition if line is equal to string end.
  if(found){                  ##Checking if found is NOT NULL.
     print val ORS $0 ORS     ##Then printing val ORS current line ORS here.
  }
  found=val=""                ##Nullifying found and val here.
}
/^begin$/{                    ##Checking condition if line is equal to string begin.
  val=""                      ##Nullifying val here.
  found=1                     ##Setting found to 1 here.
}
found{                        ##Checking if found is NOT NULL.
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0      ##Then keep adding current line to val variable here.
}
'  Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```